# Can "Which JavaScript framework (jQuery vs Dojo vs ... )?"s question please be deleted?

Tags: support, questions, locked, historical-lock

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs) is locked meaning I can not delete-vote it.

<s>Update: Robert has unlocked it. If you feel like me that it does more harm than good, both to the JavaScript community and StackOverflow's reputation - please delete vote it like I just did.</s>

**Update**: Robert has now deleted it, thanks :)

It is very outdated and contains a lot of information that's not relevant anymore. It's a good indicator of why are library recommendation questions not welcome in Stack Overflow anymore.

On top of it, none of it can be edited because it is locked which amplifies the problem even more.

It's an upvote library popularity contest on a library fight that has long been done and this question pretends to the untrained eye to be relevant where in practice it is no longer helpful.

Can it please be deleted?

Comment: Did you flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's a good idea, given the amount of upvotes it has (over 500) I assumed community consensus would be required. Would flagging it have been more appropriate?

Comment: You can certainly try; however, historical lock posts are *expected* to be out of date by now. That said, I wouldn't shed a tear if that post was nuked.

Comment: delete with extreme prejudice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>I've unlocked it for you.</s>

Instead of deleting it, consider updating the *accepted answer* to consolidate the other answers and bring it up to date, and I will place a canonical lock on it.

As to the question in your title, not a chance.  It's got three hundred thousand views.  If you really want it gone, you're going to have to muster the 20 delete votes that it will take to make it gone.

The question already got deleted once, by 10 community members.  Since it doesn't seem to be reasonably salvageable (and it's already attracted one reopen vote), I'm deleting.

You're welcome.  You can all now go on about your lives.

Comment: So, why did you delete the comments here? Also, this is what I meant http://i.imgur.com/0ZZEOUT.png

Comment: You don't have delete privileges?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I can go on about my life!

Comment: Awesome! Take that @BilltheLizard ;-)

Comment: In all fairness to Bill, he undeleted and locked the question over a year ago, when the information in it was probably more up to date.  But this information is all readily available in Google (in a more up to date form), if anyone cares to do some [cursory research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks).

Comment: @RobertHarvey let us not forget that library questions were not nearly as off topic over a year ago. I think Bill's decision to was on-par with the site policy back then.